# Printing an encoded string

Tags: php, cakephp

I was looking at this question ( [Is this a CakePHP hacking of some kind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638352/is-this-a-cakephp-hacking-of-some-kind) ), and when I was looking at the code, I saw this line:

```
$wp_cw_kses_split = '>=^/E]u*PDAF$!V'^']O;N18*L%*"2MN8';
```

When I echo this, it echos `create_function`.

How does that work?  I mean how is that even a string?  There are unescaped `'` inside it.

Demo: http://ideone.com/rk2Og

Comment: Herp derp.  My brain read that all as one long string, I didn't notice the `^` there. =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doing a bitwise XOR operation on two strings, `'>=^/E]u*PDAF$!V'` and `']O;N18*L%*"2MN8'`.

```
var_dump('>' ^ ']'); // string(1) "c"
var_dump('=' ^ 'O'); // string(1) "r"
var_dump('^' ^ ';'); // string(1) "e"
// ... etc
```

The bitwise XOR operation is done on the ASCII code of the characters, so for the first one,

```
">" = 62 (ASCII) = 0111110
 ^  = XOR          -------
"]" = 93 (ASCII) = 1011101
==========================
"c" = 99 (ASCII) = 1100011
```

Comment: You know, I didn't even notice the `^` sign there.  I read it all as one string.  I was a little confused.  Guess I need more <strike>coffee</strike> Mountain Dew.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise XOR operation on strings, which means that the ascii values of the characters are XORed. [Manual Example 2](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.bitwise.php)

You have two different strings:
`>=^/E]u*PDAF$!V` and `]O;N18*L%*"2MN8`

Comment: Ah, that would explain it.  I saw it all as one string, and was a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

It's an expression, operation of two strings:

```
       1: '>=^/E]u*PDAF$!V'
operator: ^ - bitwise XOR
       2: ']O;N18*L%*"2MN8'
```

As you can see, the `'` are not "unescaped" but this is by intention. It only looks a bit cryptic, so the brain does not read it as three things but one thing (the visual pattern of the end of the line is just too attracting).

Comment: Yeah, I saw it all as one string, and was a little confused.